# What is the correct way to persist entities based on other entities being updated in the same transaction?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, wildfly, jta

##### Description

I'm trying to persist JPA Entities in a Wildfly Web Application based on entities currently being updated in the same JTA transaction.

What needs to happen is when an entity of some type is being updated by the EntityManager, a custom strategy based on the entity type needs to run a custom JPQL query in order to find what records need to be additionally persisted into the database within the same transaction as the original entities that have been updated.

##### Things I tried

##### First Try

The thing I tried is using `javax.persistence` events such as `@PreUpdate` event in order to  gather all updated entities that I'm interested of. Since `javax.persistence` events do not allow the direct usage of `EntityManager` or `Query` objects, I store the entities in a map in a `TransactionScoped` bean. Then via CDI event, like:

```
 void beforeTransactionCommit(@Observes(during = TransactionPhase.BEFORE_COMPLETION) @Initialized(TransactionScoped.class) final Object ignored){
        //find records to be persisted and persist them through the EntityManager
    }
```

I find all the records that I need to persist based on the stored updated entities and persist them for the current transaction.

This seems to mostly work, but sometimes the `javax.persistence` events are called after the given CDI event, so I may not register the updated entity in time.

##### Second Try

The second thing I tried was again using the `javax.persistence` events, but instead of CDI event for listening for the transaction before completion, I use transaction `Synchronization` which I register via `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry.registerInterposedSynchronization`. In `Synchronization.beforeCompletion()` method implementation I find all the records that need to be created, persist  them with the `EntityManager` and then manually flush it, as the managed flush of the `EntityManager` already has happened before the synchronization call.

```
    @Override
    public void beforeCompletion() {
        convertEntitiesToRecords();
        registry.flushRecords();

        //manual flush needed in transaction synchronization to flush the records
        entityManager.flush();
    }
```

The problem with this approach is that while it works, the Spec of the `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry.registerInterposedSynchronization` says the following:

> The beforeCompletion callback will be invoked in the transaction
> context of the transaction bound to the current thread at the time
> this method is called. Allowable methods include access to resources,
> e.g. Connectors. No access is allowed to "user components" (e.g. timer
> services or bean methods), as these might change the state of data
> being managed by the caller, and might change the state of data that
> has already been flushed by another caller of
> registerInterposedSynchronization. The general context is the
> component context of the caller of registerInterposedSynchronization.

So it at least seems that using the `EntityManager` and `TransactionScoped` bean along with the `registerInterposedSynchronization` synchronization is against the accepted contract of usage of the method.

Comment: Events might not be the spot for the logic you are attempting. As you've seen, JPA is a transaction listener itself and its beforeCompletion method calculates changes and synchronizes to the DB. Putting JPA artifacts into the context during lifecycle events isn't supported by the specification as the provider may already have calculated all changes to the context - there is no way to signal to the provider what has changed and recalculate everything, and the state of the context is dirty as changes might be partially in already. Maybe use service methods/logic for this instead

Comment: @Chris I don't actually put any JPA artifacts at the time of the received JPA events. I rather register that such events happened and then (just before the transaction commits after the JTA managed persistence unit is flushed) I persist the JPA artifacts and then commit them and flush again. Service Methods/Logic would not be sufficient as there is no way cascade events may be triggered and the project I work on is quite large, so case by case solutions are a no go.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. You must be putting JPA artifacts into the context or there is nothing to flush or commit in the transaction at all - the transaction is pointless. You should persist as you go a long - JPA manages the context as a running unit of work, and will only flush to the database when needed (ie in the beforeCompletion event) anyway, so you doing so yourself doesn't seem to be needed, and breaks the contract for the container managed persistence context. Why do that? You might try using your own persistence context and joining it to the transaction instead.

Comment: @Chris What I have currently tried you may see in my question. The only thing that I saw working results for all the cases I tried is in the section (Second Try). And as I mention there I break the contract, that is why I'm posting the question here. The thing I do in section secon try is: On entity JPA event I register the entity in a queue managed by a TransactionScoped bean. As the jpa events are triggered while the persistence context is flushing and I cannot do EM related stuff I register an Interposed transaction sync where I do everything.Query/persist/flush new records based on the que

Comment: My question was on the why you do this. As mentioned, this is service layer logic; I don't see the point of pushing/delaying the persist/merge/delete JPA calls to later on in a beforeCompletion type event - and it isn't supported in the JTA lifecycles. If your second solution works, great, but it is an implementation detail that might change or you are hitting issues you don't notice yet. You are probably fine if the listener order remains consistent, but IMO what you are doing in events belongs in the service layer as is the standard pattern.

Comment: @Chris I totally agree with you that my current solution is dangerous. That is why I seek a proper one. The problem is that I dont seems to understand the idea of solving this into the service layer and how it would work for me. The main problem I hit is that we talk about 1M+ lines of code here. I cant just go and modify all services that exist. Not to mantion that modifying services itself would no do the job as as some cascade entity calls happen which dont go through the method calls of the service layer. Please let me know if I miss something, but it seems to it is rather unpleasent .